# How to add MUL key to table rows in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I‌ have a table like this:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| liker | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| liker_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I‌ know how to change the field names using PHPMyAdmin. But wondering how to add `MUL` key to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the columns using `change column`, and add the index using `add index`:

```
alter table TheTable change column post post_id int;
alter table TheTable change column liker liker_id int;
alter table TheTable add index(post_id);
alter table TheTable add index(liker_id);
```

Change `TheTable` by your table name.